# How to put the arrays in order of most recent in Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

so im trying to see if there's a way to order the specific documents from most recent to oldest
is there a way to do it from firestore? or do I have to code it ?

this is the code on how I get the specific document ids im just using UUID().string which generated one for me

```
func quoteMeVariables(){

    let quotemodel = quoteME()

    quotemodel.quoteMEid = UUID().uuidString
    quotemodel.author = authorTextfield.text
    quotemodel.QuoteText = quoteMeTextfield.text
    quotemodel.saveQuoteMetoFirebase(quotemodel) //


    hud.textLabel.text = "Your Quote Has Been Sent Successfully!"
    hud.show(in: self.view)
    hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDSuccessIndicatorView()
    hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 3.0)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0){

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add a timestamp to be able to sort based on that

Comment: There are a number of solutions but what you're showing in your question is not an array. That being said, if you simply add a timestamp field to each document, they can be easily sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the array inside Firestore, but if you need the array sorted, when you fetch it, you need to do it in code.
You need to add a timestamp, from the server, to your document.

[Go look here, if you don't know how.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847047/10607890)

Then you can .order(by: timestamp) on your collection, to get it sorted by timestamp.

Comment: You cannot sort an array in Firestore. An array is a fixed sequence of fields that cannot be sorted by the server. The sequence is the sequence by index. This is the downside of arrays in NoSQL databased.