# How to get server Timestamp from firebase v9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please, I need your help to get the server timestamp from **Firebase version 9**.

I've tried to follow the same approach as for Firebase v8 : `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()` but didn't work for version 9.

Is there any way to do the same thing in Firebase version 9 ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's discussed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).  Just import `serverTimestamp`.

```
import { updateDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, 'objects', 'some-id');

// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
const updateTimestamp = await updateDoc(docRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
});
```

Comment: yes you're right, Thank you.

Comment: to get the type in v9 is: import {  Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to use it in my state. : A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.0.creation`. Value: {"nanoseconds": 525000000, "seconds": 1669478590}.

Comment: I don't know what serverTimestamp do. But I assume it returns the timestamp. Which Date.now() or new Date().getTime() also does. How is serverTimestamp different?

Comment: @SanujBansal serverTimestamp is updated by Firestore itself when the document is written to firestore. It prevents clients from reporting the wrong time (change the datetime on your computer and check the value of new Date()) https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b

Answer (score 9):

If you get type error with other answers you can try this:

```
import { Timestamp} from '@firebase/firestore';

createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

Comment: How is it different from Date.now()?

Comment: Date.now() creates a number. New Date() creates Date object.

Comment: But we are wrapping new Date() with Timestamp.fromDate. From which I get that at the end we are getting timestamp which Date.now() also gives us

Comment: But Date.Now() is not same Type with Firebase Timestamp. Topic is about Firestore Timestamp. This is for getting a date suitable with Firestore Timestamp. Other solutions didn't work for me but this one was ok. So i shared as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore Database V9:

```
import { doc, updateDoc, serverTimestamp, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
const db = getFirestore(app);

const docRef = doc(db, 'yourCollection', 'yourDocId');
await updateDoc(docRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
});
```

Firebase Realtime Database V9:

```
import { serverTimestamp, ref as fbRef, getDatabase, update } from 'firebase/database';
const db = getDatabase(app);

const yourUpdatedDoc = {
  lastUpdated: serverTimestamp()
}

await update(
  fbRef(db, `/yourDocLocation`), yourUpdatedDoc
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`import {serverTimestamp} from 'firebase/firestore';`

Then simply change `timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to `timestamp: serverTimestamp()`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an answer of this question

```
import { serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
lastSeen: serverTimestamp()
```