# Get timestamp from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

How can I import `serverTimestamp()` from Firebase 9?

I've tried

```
import { serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/compat/database';
```

Here is the function https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#servertimestamp

I've found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74918994/3102325

```
import { serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/database';
```

But when calling `serverTimestamp()` it returns a simple Object

```
{
  .sv: "timestamp"
}
```

Comment: That is the expected behavior, as `{ .sv: "timestamp" }` is an instruction for the server to write its timestamp. If you want to read the actual value, you will have to listen to the location in the database that you're writing to.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, indeed. It the server generates a timestamp when passed that object resulted from function call.