# React native app crashes on android device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

(please forgive me if I don't speak English correctly)
I am a beginner and have developed an android application on react native with the use of expo.

```
type hereimport React, { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { auth, db } from '../firebase';
import { AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Input, Button, Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';

const FeedScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [addpost, setAdd] = useState(false);

  const [postText, setPostText] = useState('');

  const likes = 0;

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <AntDesign
            onPress={() => setAdd(true)}
            name="pluscircleo"
            size={27}
            color="black"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db
      .collection('posts')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const newPosts = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          newPosts.push({
            id: doc.data().id,
            createdAt: doc.data().createdAt,
            text: doc.data().text,
            author: doc.data().author,
          });
        });
        setPosts(newPosts);
      });
  }, []);

  const onAddButtonPress = () => {
    const timestamp=firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    setAdd(false);
    const data = {
      createdAt: timestamp,
      text: postText,
      id: auth?.currentUser?.email,
      author: auth?.currentUser?.displayName,
    };
    const unsubscribe = db
      .collection('posts')
      .add(data)
      .then((_doc) => {
        setPostText('');
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      });
  };

  const postItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.postview}>
        <View
          style={{
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            borderBottomColor: '#E2E2E2',
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <Avatar
            size={40}
            rounded
            title={item.author.substr(0, 1)}
            containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#6733b9' }}
          />
          <Text style={styles.autor}>{item.author}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.txt}>{item.text}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Modal visible={addpost}>
        <View>
          <Ionicons name="close" size={40} onPress={() => setAdd(false)} />
          <Text style={styles.txt2}>Add Post</Text>
          <View style={styles.form}>
            <Input
              placeholder="Enter post text"
              value={postText}
              onChangeText={(text) => setPostText(text)}
            />
            <Button title="Add" onPress={onAddButtonPress} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <FlatList
        data={posts}
        renderItem={postItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  postview: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingVertical: 'auto',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  autor: {
    fontSize: 18,
    //marginHorizontal: 40,
    marginTop: 7,
  },
  txt: {
    marginTop: 20,
    fontSize: 17,
    marginHorizontal: 40,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  txt2: {
    marginHorizontal: 'auto',
    fontSize: 40,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  form: {
    paddingTop: 80,
  },
  ava: {
    marginHorizontal: 40,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});

export default FeedScreen;
```

This is the code of the page where the app crashes. Posts are displayed here, and there is also a button to add them.Clicking on the button brings up a modal window with the form.When I click the add button, the attachment crashes, that is, when I call onAddButtonPress

please forgive me if I don't know how to ask a question

Here's the package.json and app.js code:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "eas-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "^0.15.6",
    "firebase": "^8.9.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer, DarkTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {
  Feather,
  AntDesign,
  Ionicons,
  MaterialIcons,
} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen';
import FeedScreen from './screens/FeedScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
import { Provider as PaperProvider, DarkTheme as Dark} from 'react-native-paper'

export default function App() {

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  function Home() {
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{contentStyle:{ backgroundColor:'#E5E7E6'}}}>
      <Tab.Screen
          name="Feeds"
          component={FeedScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Feeds',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialIcons name="dynamic-feed" size={24} color="grey" />
            ),
            //headerStyle:{backgroundColor: '#f4511e'}
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <AntDesign name="user" size={24} color="grey" />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings"
          component={SettingsScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <Feather name="settings" size={24} color="grey" />
            ),
          }}
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }

  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I read articles about crashes, ran on different devices

Comment: Always include a crash log. There should be an error message in the logs which helps solving issues.

Comment: Can you use something like `window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) { ... log your error to a server - *.log file ... }` ? Also, does it crash when you try the same on a desktop device, with browser window resized to mobile screen size?

Comment: @FiddlingAway I hope I understood the comment,because it's hard for me to understand English. As for this function that you mentioned, I will try to study it and test it on the project, but I did not use it. As for the browser, I tested the project in expo snack and expo go, and everything worked correctly. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event) should help. The `window.onerror` event handler can be used to obtain information about the error. You don't have to log it to a file, you can do something like `window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) { alert(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error); }`. When the error happens, the details will be displayed in an alert box. That would make it easier to track down what causes the error.

Comment: @FiddlingAway OK, thanks for the answer! I'll try to check it out soon

Comment: @FiddlingAway The error was firebase here: const timestamp=firestore. FieldValue.serverTimestamp(); I replaced this line with const timestamp=db. FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), however, it gave an Uncaught TypeError error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serverTimestamp')

Comment: This would mean that `db.FieldValue` is undefined. You can try and do something like `alert(JSON.stringify(db))` to see if your `db` object has a `FieldValue` property. Or maybe it's a typo - I'm seeing a space between db and FieldValue: `db.` `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Comment: @FiddlingAway Thank you!I'll try it now.As for the space, there is no space in the code

Comment: @FiddlingAway .db. FieldValue is really undefined. however i don't know how to turn to severTimestamp now

Comment: Can you do it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69519471)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway I solved the problem! I specified timestamp in the firebase initialization file. Thank you very much! Without you, I wouldn't know what to do.